# Wordpress admin-ajax.php 404 not found at Console

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I am using Nulled Theme for many years. Now 20 days ago I am getting admin-ajax.php 404 not found error.
I replace all files with old and also checked all files and plugins but nothing to works.

Error occurred on Installing plugin, update, delete and even on uploading. It gives me error at console admin-ajax.php not found.

Comment: Either it is removed or the path is not correct.

Comment: brother this file is on server and i replace all files to its original state but not work. even disabling mode_security ...